# Android: emulator unable to resolve hostname for local workstation

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I'm trying to connect to a web app running my computer from the android emulator using the `apache httpClient`.

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://dev.example.com:8443/gatekeeper/rs/authenticate/login");
post.setHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams));
HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
response = client.execute(post);
```

I do have the required android manifest configuration as below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I did check I can access the internet from the browser on the emulator. I can not access the app URL from the browser as well. My application also fails with an error

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "dev.example.com": No address associated with hostname

My application works fine when used with IP address of my computer. I also have entry in my hosts file

> 192.168.1.8   dev.example.com

What can I be missing here? It looks like android emulator can't look in to my hosts file to resolve the host name!

Comment: I guess android developer made a decision to not to allow(not to enable) the emulator to connect to the local workstation using a hostname. It can connect to the local box with the IP address though. Sounds not fair to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `Connectivity` programitically before calling for response

or If there is no response the also this exception is thrown

Comment: The program works fine when I use the IP address, I think that indicates that it's not a connectivity issue? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: if it says unable to resolve host that means its a connectivity issues may be due to internet, ports or also due to protocols may be like https or http

Comment: The same code works fine when run from eclipse(in a main method in java program). That makes me suspicious if there is something wrong with the android emulator.